# Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I using the Wordpress plugin `super socializer` but when i login with details i face

> The "Facebook SDK returned an error: 
>   Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data.

Please help.Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have saved exactly the following two domains in the `App Domains` option in Facebook app settings (

step 11 http://support.heateor.com/how-to-get-facebook-app-id/

):

```
www.pontoxis.com.br
pontoxis.com.br
```

..and exactly the following two urls in the Valid Oauth Redirect URIs option (step 9 http://support.heateor.com/how-to-get-facebook-app-id/):
https://pontoxis.com.br
https://pontoxis.com.br/?SuperSocializerAuth=Facebook